# CKEditor with CKFinder - removing the 'Browse Server' button, but only for certain profiles

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

I have a number of CKEditor profiles, some of which use CKFinder to upload images. However, for one profile I want to remove the option to browse the server within the CKFinder dialogue, whilst retaining it for another profile.

Is this possible?

There's a similar question answered here, but it only deals with removing the button globally (as far as I can see):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610041/ckeditor-with-ckfinder-disable-filebrowser-keep-upload-functionality

Comment: what drupal modules are you using ? just the drupal ckeditor module ? wysiwyg module + ckeditor !?!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else end up on this link to look for a solution. 
I am using wysiwyg, IMCE, IMCE wysiwyg api bridge, and ckeditor.

```
Configuration -> Media -> IMCE -> Role-profile assignments
```

select User-1 or any other profile according to your setting.